# snap applications without permissions to write to home directory when using sssd

Tags: permissions, skype, snap, sssd

I have set up sssd and joined my 18.04 LTS workstation to the company domain.  Most things work OK except for a couple of snap applications.  When trying to run them I get errors creating files in ~/snap.

:~$ skype
cannot create user data directory: /home/[domain]/[user]/snap/skype/48: Permission denied

Skype works if I run it as root, however I would prefer not to do that.

The mail app hiri however refuses to let me write in it even if I club it with chmod -R 777

~$ hiri
cannot create user data directory: /home/[domain]/[user]/snap/hiri/55: Permission denied

What am I missing?

Comment: Are `[domain]` and `[user]` actually there, ,`[]` and all, or is this an obfuscation?

Comment: My `pathlld` script will show you more information. https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld.git - Bash script to answer "Why can't I read/write that file?"

Comment: Hi waltinator, 

thanks for the respone.  [doman] and [user] are indeed obfuscations.  Perhaps I'm being overly cautious there?

Output:
https://pastebin.com/WZYstUb6

Comment: I am seeing this permissions failure with more and more snap apps.  Inkscape now.

Does anyone know how to fix this?  Am I the only one with this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is due to the user home folder being part of the domain.

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure apparmor
```

Then, specify "/home/[DOMAIN]/" as an additional user home directory.
This should resolve the permission issue for all the applications

Comment: Shravya - you are officially my new hero!  I am now happily running snap apps in my domain account.  
Thank you.

Comment: I really can't take the credit for it. One of my teammates told me this solution :)